# What am I missing here? Basic file i/o & string.find()

Tags: python

I've got this text file which lists all my movies and I thought I'd put them into a database of sorts. So first steps, read the text file, do some small manipulation and rewrite the file.

So, some lines contain multiple movie names separated by "AKA" so I need to turn that into two separate lines before I write it to the new file.

I have now struck to problems:

1. Losing the first line in the output file (which I solved by using an additional read/write outside the main loop omitting the check for "AKA" at this stage.
2. The `if` statement checking the result of the `string.find("AKA")` is never triggered.

The code is here:

```
fd1 = open("Movies_List_2.txt", "r")
fd2 = open("Movies_List_3.txt", "w")

inp_line = fd1.read()         # This is to fix the missing first line in the output file
fd2.write(inp_line.strip() + "\n")

for line in fd1:
    inp_line = fd1.read()
    x = inp_line.find("ÄKA")
    if x == -1:          # <=== This never triggers
       l = len(inp_line)
       extn = inp_line[l-3:]
       year = inp_line[l-8:l-4]
       inp_line2 = inp_line[x+4:l-9]
       inp_line = inp_line[:x-1]
       fd2.write(inp_line + " " + year + "." + extn + "\n")
       fd2.write(inp_line + " " + year + "." + extn + "]n")
    else:
       fd2.write(inp_line)
      
fd1.close()
fd2.close()
```

And a sample of the input file is here:

```
20 Million Miles to Earth 1957
20,000 Leagues Under the Sea 1954
2001 A Space Odyssey 1968
2010 The Year We Make Contact 1981
2017 AKA Shockwave 2017           <====== This should trigger the test
2036 Origin Unknown 2018
2046 2004
2050 2018
2067 2020
```

I'm almost certain that there is a fundamental I'm missing here, but I've spent a lot of time over it with no success.

Can someone point out where this code is going wrong?

Comment: `x = inp_line.find("ÄKA")`: you wrote AKA with a diaeresis, is it a typo ?

Comment: `inp_line = fd1.read()` reads the entire file so at `for line in fd1:` the file pointer is at the end.

Comment: Sorry, May.D it is a typo. Doesn't exist in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
fd1 = open("Movies_List_2.txt", "r")
...
for line in fd1:
    inp_line = fd1.read()
...
fd1.close()
```

looks like you have mixing 2 different ways to read text file in `python`. These are:

**reading everything as once**, for example if I want to know number of `e` letters I can do:

```
f = open(filename, "r")
content = f.read()
f.close()
print(content.count("e"))
```

**processing file line-by-line**, for example if I want to know number of `e` letters in each line I can do:

```
f = open(filename, "r")
for line in f:
    print(line.count("e"))
f.close()
```

Note that `open` might be also used as context manager, which simply speaking does handle closing for you, following is my 1st example using that feature:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
     content = f.read()
print(content.count("e"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside other dubious code in your script (`"ÄKA"` and `"AKA"` are not the same string), your test never triggers because you never loop inside the for.

`inp_line = fd1.read()` will read **the whole file** inside `inp_line`, not just one line! This causes the file descriptor to reach the end of file, so when you try to get the "next" line in:

```py
for line in fd1:
```

the StopIteration triggers and you never actually iterate.

The solution is to just iterate line-by-line in the for loop:

```
fd1 = open("Movies_List_2.txt", "r")
fd2 = open("Movies_List_3.txt", "w")

for line in fd1:
    x = line.find("ÄKA")
    if x == -1:          # <=== This never triggers
       ...
```

(Note that you need to restructure your loop to use `line` instead of `inp_line`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution you need.just a little fix.

```py
fd1 = open("Movies_List_2.txt", "r")
fd2 = open("Movies_List_3.txt", "w")

for line in fd1:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.find("AKA")>0:
        print(line.split('AKA'))
        line_a,line_b = line.split('AKA')
        fd2.write(line_a+"\n")
        fd2.write(line_b.strip()+"\n")
    else:
        fd2.write(line+"\n")
      
fd1.close()
fd2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

```
# Forget to close the files.
with open("Movies_List_2.txt") as fdIn:
    with open("Movies_List_3.txt", "w") as fdOut:

        # The thing...
        for line in fdIn:  # Read file line by line
            line = line.strip()

            # Single line movies. Just copy
            if 'AKA' not in line:
                print(line, file=fdOut)
                continue

            # Lines with multiple movies
            head, year = line[:-5], line[-4:]
            for movie in head.split('AKA'):  # Split movies
                movie = movie.strip()
                print(f'{movie} {year}', file=fdOut)  # Write move adding the year
```